# Position the blocks, vertical align

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

My code :

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>
<style>
    .grid-item{display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width: 20%;}
</style>
```

How can I position the blocks one under another without using absolute positioning?

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like this :

---

#### Demo

```css
.grid-column {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
 
.grid-cell {
   vertical-align: top;
   background: #a00606;
   color: #fff;
   margin: 10px 20px;
   padding: 5px;
   text-align: center;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-family : Arial, Verdana, 'sans-serif';
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-column">
    <div class="grid-cell">DIV#1<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></div>
    <div class="grid-cell">DIV#5<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></div>
</div>
<div class="grid-column">
    <div class="grid-cell">DIV#2<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></div>
    <div class="grid-cell">DIV#6<br/><br/><br/><br/></div>
</div>
<div class="grid-column">
    <div class="grid-cell">DIV#3<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></div>
    <div class="grid-cell">DIV#7<br/><br/><br/><br/></div>
</div>
<div class="grid-column">
    <div class="grid-cell">DIV#4<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></div>
    <div class="grid-cell">DIV#8<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Surely you shouldn't use br tags to set the height like that, unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

I read your image wrong, I believe this is what you wanted:

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fzrk5uwa/5/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item2">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item2">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>

</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid-item2 push">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item2 push">8</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
 .grid-item {
   color: #fff;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   width: 100px;
   height: 50px;
   margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
   background-color: #cdcdcd;
 }

 .grid-item2 {
   color: #fff;
   vertical-align: bottom;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100px;
   height: 105px;
   margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
   background-color: gold;
 }

 .push {
   margin-top: -50px;
 }
```

OLD ANSWER BELOW - - - - - - - - -

Use the 'display: block' deceleration along with 'float: left' on the div's parent wrapper.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fzrk5uwa/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item2"></div>

</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="grid-item2"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="grid-item2"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .grid-item { 
         display: block; 
         vertical-align: top; 
         width: 100px; 
         height: 50px; 
         margin: 5px 0 0 5px; 
         background-color: #cdcdcd;
     }

      .grid-item2 { 
         display: block; 
         width: 100px; 
         height: 105px; 
         margin: 5px 0 0 5px; 
         background-color: gold;
     }

     .wrapper {
         float: left;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
**display:inline;** to **display:block;**
```

There is a 'Tryit' exercise

Here -- **http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_display_inline**

Answer (score 0):

Use 4 wrapper divs with `width: 25%`, a fixed height and `display: inline-table`

Then put two blocks / divs inside each of them, define them as `display: table-row`, give them a height and put some content in them.

see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzWPGV

Answer (score 0):

You can use `box-sizing: border-box;` with `float:left;` element for align  side by side in horizontal and it is responsive also.

```css
.grid-column {
   float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
 
.grid-cell {
   float: left;
   background: #a00606;
   color: #fff;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width: 18%;
   height: 150px;
   margin: 5px 15px;
   padding: 5px;
   text-align: center;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-family : Arial, Verdana, 'sans-serif';
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-column">
    <div class="grid-cell">DIV#1</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">DIV#2</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">DIV#3</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">DIV#4</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">DIV#5</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">DIV#6</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">DIV#7</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">DIV#8</div>
</div>
```